# HelpProvider in UWP App

Tags: uwp, modal-dialog, helper

Since I cannnot find a Windows Help Provider in a UWP app, I'm using a Button with ??.

I would like to put a ? at the top right of my page that would open a ContentDialog as my Help Screen.  Here is the ContentDialog I open with my Button.

```
<ContentDialog
x:Class="EMR3.Views.MainContentDialog"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:EMR3.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
PrimaryButtonText="OK"
PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
 x:Name="mainHelpDlg">

    <ContentDialog.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="Main Screen Help"
           FontStyle="Italic"
           FontWeight="ExtraBlack" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentDialog.TitleTemplate>

    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <WebView x:Name="MainWebView" Source="http://www.xxxxxxx.com/Help_p1.html" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Grid.Row="3"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="400" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
</ContentDialog>
```

Is there a better way to show Help screens with no Help Provider in UWP? My preference is to place the "?" on the right side of the Title Bar.

Comment: Not today... please consider adding this as a suggestion [on UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com).